# Opening Files in Haskell using String parameters

Tags: file, haskell, io

I am learning Haskell and I'm not very good at it yet...
Some of the tutorials I've read ([Haskell's String IO](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tutorials/Programming_Haskell/String_IO) and [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)) have explained a lot of things about IO, but I still could not write my desired function:

```
TutorialCopy inputName outputName = do
                                    contents <- Str.readFile inputName  -- Opens the target File.
                                    writeFile outputName contents       -- Creates the destination File.
```

The Idea here was to read a file based on the Input File's location ('inputName') and have it's contents transferred to the Output File ('outputName'). I have also tried the function type:

```
TutorialCopy :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
```

Or even:

```
TutorialCopy :: String -> String -> IO ()
```

With no success whatsoever, as GHCi returns signature errors when I declare the signature or a data constructor error when I don't.

I appreciate all the help, thank you!

Comment: What's `Str` here? It seems odd to use `Str.readFile` but then use a plain `writeFile` instead of, say, `Str.writeFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell has some enforced named conventions. Function names must start with a lowercase letter, data types and constructors start with an uppercase letter. Change the name of your function to `tutorialCopy`, that should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, it helped but didn't solve the problem... This time it generated a different error: `IOTutorial01.hs:14:94:
    Couldn't match type `Str.ByteString' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Str.ByteString
    In the second argument of `writeFile', namely `contents'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: writeFile outputName contents
    In the expression:
      do { contents <- Str.readFile inputName;
           writeFile outputName contents }`

Comment: @Zeh That means that you're trying to use the `ByteString` interface for reading files instead of the `String` interface.  `ByteString` is a type provided by a library that has a lot of useful applications where `String` just doesn't cut it, and it's great for things like network IO.

Comment: @bheklilr the thing is, I haven't used any `ByteString` explicitly on my code, which is exactly like the one I have in the question.

Comment: @Zeh, first, it's a different problem. Second, if you want help with it, please add the definition of ``Str`` to your question (or, even better, just create a minimal working example altogether).

Comment: @Zeh You're using `Str.readFile` which I'm assuming is from one of the `ByteString` modules although it's hard to say because you don't have that import statement in your code example, but the built in `readFile` returns a `String`.

Comment: @Bogdan that was exactly the problem... I had hidden a `import qualified Data.ByteString as Str` in the code, I feel so dumb now... Thank you all for the help, it was very useful!